# JSON : There is a cycle in the hierarchy

Tags: java

```
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name="order_id")
    private int orderid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private UserEntity user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ordersBid",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<BidPriceEntity> bidOrders;
}
public class BidPriceEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_Id",nullable=false)
    private OrderEntity ordersBid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_Id",nullable=false)
    private UserEntity driver;      

    @Column(name="bid_price")
    private double bidPrice;
}
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name="order_id")
    private int orderid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private UserEntity user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ordersBid",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<BidPriceEntity> bidOrders;
}
```

Here are the three entities.I am trying to tansfer the data(retrieved from database) to JsonArray.it always get error :There is a cycle in the hierarchy!

how should I set the : JsonConfig (setJsonPropertyFilter) properties to get
rid of this error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it said :  There is a cycle in the hierarchy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are two options for cycle - write own serializer, use `@JsonIgnore`. Like in your code - `OrderEntity` contains list of `BidPriceEntities`, which in turn contains reference to `OrderEntity`. Mark `ordersBid` with `@JsonIgnore` and it should work. At list serialization... If you don't have access to the class - try [mixins](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Comment: Thx Michal ,I hava added the serializer,and Json annotation. its working now. thank u very much